# Extracting the position of a number from a deliminated column in DAX using another column as reference?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to create a hierarchy with some work data, and I want to use a fully drawn out pathway to find where any given employee in command of that list is.
Here's a splice of what my table looks like

| Full hierarchy | Employee |
| --- | --- |
| 1 , 158 , 134163 , 123287 , 160898 , 168221 , 24382 , 121200 , 108896 | 160898 |
| 1 , 158 , 134163 , 123287 , 160898 , 168221 , 24382 , 121200 , 108896 | 121200 |

I want to use the value in the employee column to automate a split on the original column, where the outcome becomes this

| Full hierarchy | Employee | Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 , 158 , 134163 , 123287 , 160898 , 168221 , 24382 , 121200 , 108896 | 160898 | 1 , 158 , 134163 , 123287 , 160898 |
| 1 , 158 , 134163 , 123287 , 160898 , 168221 , 24382 , 121200 , 108896 | 121200 | 1 , 158 , 134163 , 123287 , 160898 , 168221 , 24382 , 121200 |

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `FIND`, `LEFT`. Finding the position afterwards (rather than just yielding the string) can be done by replacing `,` with `|` and using `PATHLENGTH`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, Not sure what you're going for here? The method you're using does not allow me to reference the column where the employee number is, which is the main point of my quandary.

Comment: It's unclear in what context you have the employee, then. Obviously to find the employee in a given string you need to access both that string and the employee. Keep in mind that in DAX you can use `VAR` to introduce computed tables or lookup values in other tables based on the current context. Alternatively, if you need to literally operate on every row in a table with employee numbers, you can use a computed column (but this may require you to pull in the hierarchy in the table itself).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Added context to the question, sorry for any misunderstandings in the original.

Comment: Right -- so if that's your table, you can add a computed column defined as `Outcome = LEFT('Table'[Hierarchy], FIND('Table'[Employee], 'Table'[Hierarchy]) - 1 + LEN('Table'[Employee]))`.